# netbeans text not allowed in element form error

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm pretty new to HTML and trying to figure the following error: 
I'm using netbeans (7.4) and I am trying to make a Web project with Servlets. When I use the defaults that we are instructed to use (yes it's a homework assignment, but my issue is ancillary to the actual assignment, so I don't think I'm trying to cheat here), Java 5 EE, it creates index.jsp. If I write HTML in that .jsp file, such as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head> <title>Foo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8084/MyProject/MyClass" method=GET>
    How many Foos and Bars?
    <select name="Foo">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Bar">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

it works perfectly fine. However, we are told to use .html files instead of .jsp files, and when I copy this file over (from a .jsp to a .html), without the following line (which causes it's own error if included)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

then Netbeans tells me:

```
"Text not allowed in element 'form' in this context"
```

So how do I get text in-between some of my form-fields, when it is an HTML document, not a .jsp?

Comment: may be try changing  `method="GET"`

Comment: Also try enclosing your text in `<p>` tags. JSP doesn't like free-floating text, and `form` is a container for form elements, not text per se.

Comment: **sigh**. Eventually I will learn things, I swear. <p>How many foos and bars</p> no longer errors; if you elevate to an answer, @chrylis, I'll accept. Note for the record though, free-floating text works fine in the .jsp, but not in the .html; your phrasing suggest the other way around.

Comment: @dwanderson You said that the JSP was complaining, but *not* the HTML. I thought Transitional would be okay with that.

Comment: ah, perhaps my post was unclear, and I see now how it might be - the first portion, when the HTML is written in the .jsp is fine; when I copy it over to a .html is when it errors. I'll try to clarify it better, sorry

Comment: @dwanderson Firefox certainly doesn't have any problems with it in Transitional, but who knows what's legal in Transitional? Tag defensively. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text inside `<p>` tags. Browsers are awfully forgiving (this HTML file works fine in Firefox), but free-floating text should be captured inside appropriate container elements (generally, `<p>`, `<div>`, or the HTML5 semantic elements).